# Update all values (n) in a column in a table made in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I created a table in a power shell script with some data in it. I need to find a way to do something like a replace in a column. For every value (x) i find in the column, change it to (y). How is this possible i power shell?

Thnaks in advance. Also, I could not find anything like this from google, and it has to be done after the table is already built, not while building the table columns and rows. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to build the table?

Comment: @mjolinor I'm sure he's referring to the resultant table from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641552/combine-two-tables-that-are-similar-with-two-columns-different-using-powershell) that I answered for him earlier today.

Comment: The problem was, that when I combined two SQL tables of data into one in the script, the columns that were not in both tables were dropped. I corrected this by using a simple method in the SQL query. I did a "select as" to alias the columns names to match. Then the sorting worked properly when they were combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by a table. However, assuming you are referring to a collection of objects, it's simple:

```
$collectionToUpdate | Where-Object { $_.PropertyToCheck -eq $valueToCheck } | ForEach-Object { $_.PropertyToCheck = $replacementValue }
```

Obviously, replace the names of the variables and property with the correct values from your code.

Comment: I was speaking of a DataTable.

Comment: Yea, I realized I was making this way more difficult then it needed to be. Thanks.